# Tensor Product between Nabla operator and a vector or tensor field

Tags: operators, solid-mechanics

I am recently studying solid mechanics and I met a problem regarding Nabla operator. I am trying to prove the following relation:
$$\nabla \otimes\textbf{u}=\frac{\partial\textbf{u}}{\partial x_{i}} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{i} \tag{1}$$

where $\nabla$ is the Nabla operator and $(\bullet)$ represents a smooth vector or tensor field. It is defined as follows,
$$
\nabla(\bullet) = \frac{\partial(\bullet)}{\partial x_{j}}\textbf{e}_j
$$
and $\textbf{u}$ denotes a vector field and we have $\textbf{u}=u_i\textbf{e}_i$ and $\textbf{e}_i(i=1,2,3)$ is a set of orthonomal Cartesian basis vectors.

To prove equation(1), I compute both sides of the equation and get
$$
LHS=\nabla \otimes\textbf{u} = \frac{\partial(\bullet)}{\partial x_{j}}\textbf{e}_j\otimes u_i\textbf{e}_i = \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_{j}} \textbf{e}_j\otimes \textbf{e}_i
$$
and
$$
RHS=\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial x_{i}} \otimes \mathbf{e}_{i} = \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_{i}}\textbf{e}_j\otimes\textbf{e}_i
$$

It seems that $LHS \neq RHS$. I am wondering if there is any step where a mistake happens. Can you help me?

Comment: If you're trying to prove something, you need a place to start.  Your first equation looks like it *defines* the $\nabla$ operator, so it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thx for reminding! I have updated the problem.

Comment: I don't understand this notation.  Do  you have a reference for this?.  In particular, is $\nabla \otimes \mathbf u$ supposed to be the action of $\nabla$ on the field $\mathbf u$? To me, $\nabla \otimes \mathbf u$ looks like the tensor product of an operator with a vector.

Comment: Yes, you can refer to *Nonlinear Solid Mechanics A Continuum Approach for Engineering by Gerhard A. Holzapfel*, chapter 1.8, eq(1.264)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not prove that relation by applying a tensor product between the nabla operator and a tensor or vector field, because the nabla operator is not a vector or tensor field. You must start the proof by calculating the directional derivative of $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})$ in an arbitrary direction $\mathbf{d}$:
\begin{align*}
(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{u})\cdot\mathbf{d}&=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}a}\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}+a\mathbf{d})\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial{y_{i}}}\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial a}\quad\text{where }y_{i}\equiv x_{i}+ad_{i}\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial{y_{i}}}d_{i}\\
&=\frac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial{x_{i}}}d_{i}\\
&=\frac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial{x_{i}}}(\mathbf{e}_{i}\cdot\mathbf{d})\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial{x_{i}}}\otimes\mathbf{e}_{i}\right)\cdot\mathbf{d}
\end{align*}
Therefore $$\nabla\otimes\mathbf{u}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial{x_{i}}}\otimes\mathbf{e}_{i}$$
Note that $\mathbf{u}$ may be a smooth vector or tensor field.

Comment: You reasoning on the right-hand side of the eq is correct. But why can you express $(\nabla\otimes \textbf{u}) \cdot \textbf{d}$ with that limit? Can you give more detail?

Comment: By the way, I think your statement that nabla operator can not be treated as a vector or tensor is correct and that's the mistake I made in my reasoning. So I am wondering now if this operation involving nabla operator is just an operation rule defined by someone and we should treat it as a rule or definition instead of reasoning it.

Comment: I expressed $(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{u})\cdot\mathbf{d}$ with that limit because that is the equation that defines the tensor $(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{u})$. In other words, the tensor $(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{u})$ is defined as the tensor that satisfies the expression $$(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{u})\cdot\mathbf{d}=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}a}\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}+a\mathbf{d})$$ for all vectors $\mathbf{d}$.